# TCL code dependency generator

Tags: ide, tcl, expect, dependency-graph

I have a large code base written on expect/TCL version 5.39. I need to get a good understanding of the flow, is there a good dependency graph generator for TCL or a great TCL IDE which takes me to the procedure/variable definition/declaration when I ctrl+click(or something similar) on the user procedure.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: ActiveState's [Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide) IDE probably does this.

Comment: Eclipse with the Tcl DLTK plugin might do this; I've not played with that for a while…

Answer (score 0):

I have installed [Tcl DLTK](http://www.eclipse.org/dltk/) in my Eclipse Kepler and it does what you are looking for.

To install the plugin:

- Download the plugin
- In Eclipse: Help -> Install Software -> Add... -> Local...

The first time you create a new Tcl project you will be asked for the location of your tcl interpreter.